# is there a way to add multiple events to the $("body").on() to work when a list is changed or a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on('change', '#FilterSize1,#FilterSize2', function () {
```

where the related function will fire when the `filterSize1` or `FilerSize2` is changed. now I want to modify the above to allow the same function to fire when an button is clicked also ? so can anyone advice if     `$("body").on` allow to define multiple events (when a list is changed or when a button is clicked ??) ?

Comment: `$("body").on('change click', '#FilterSize1,#FilterSize2', function () {`

Answer (score 3):

Just name the function.

Although you can have `.on("change click",function()` - it looks strange when you have things that change and things that you click. For example if you click a select the function will be executed regardless of change. It does make it more readable too.

```
function something() {}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").on('change', '#FilterSize1,#FilterSize2', something);
  $("body").on('click', '#button,#button1', something);
});
```

on neater:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").on('change', '#FilterSize1,#FilterSize2', something)
           .on('click', '#button,#button1', something);
});
```

Comment: of course on the same screen I will not have the dropdown and the button,, either one of them will occur,, as this is a general script that should work on all my current views.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple events with space separated

```
$("body").on('change click', .......
```

In case you want different handlers for them then

```
$("body").on({'click': function(){ .... }, 'change' : function(){..........},'selector')
```

For binding events for separate elements, you should bind twice with different selectors

```
$("body").on('click','selector1',handler).on('change','selector2',handler)
```

Comment: I like the second version. The first is tricky - if I click a select it will trigger the function too

Comment: @mplungjan : yup it will :)